# Impossible to edit a question where there is too little context around the code

Tags: support, edits, code-formatting, quality-filter

I'm trying to edit [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259953/phpdomdocumentload-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity), consisting mostly of code and output trace. It lacked formatting and tags. However, I could not submit my edit because I got the following error:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Since I'm not the original poster, I cannot provide a context I do not know, and thus the question formatting must remain as cluttered as it is now... Is there a way to bypass this limitation? Is there a way I can format the code in a way that does not trigger this error?

Comment: Probably old question posted before this filter was in place.. post link here and we'll see.

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : the original question passed the filter **because** of its bad formatting.

Comment: Link to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259953/phpdomdocumentload-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity) (now edited, I don't really know why I couldn't do it).

Comment: Either you formatted the error message as code too (resulting in code only post) or maybe this filter is set only on suggested edit.

Comment: It's exactly what I did, I formatted the error message as code and the actual editor did not. Thank you. If you want to rephrase that as an answer...